# Database access or file access more faster using ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I am working on a simple Chat application using jquery/ajax and php, and saving chat messages in the mysql database.My question is for saving chat message which is more faster database,text file or xml file,and which is more faster to retreive data using ajax.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Database, especially as the volume of data grows, because you can index tables for efficiency... and code for selective retrieval from a database is far easier than using xpath or similar

Comment: but when the amount of data become large is it slow down?
and i also need to keep the chat history for long time,so cant clear the database

Comment: Prevent slowdown for retrieval of data from a large volume database by __indexing__... I did use the word `index` in my original comment. Using a text file or XML will always be slower than a database precisely because you can't index them effectively